# Posting an ajax request in Laravel-5

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

I am trying to send an ajax post request in my page, but I'm getting an error in console.

```
POST http://local.bazaar.com/testimonials/submit 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Routes.php

```php
Route::post('/testimonials/submit','TestimonialsController@savetesti');
```

Ajax.js

```js
$("#submitTestimonial").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/testimonials/submit',
        method: 'POST',               
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            die;
        }
    })

    return false;
});
```

TestimonialsController.php

```php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Input;
use Request;

class TestimonialsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Perform validations on user data
     * Hash Password
     * Create
     * @return Response
     */
    public function savetesti()
    {
        // Getting all post data
        print_r("success");
    }
}    
?>
```

viewPage->

```html
<div class="testimonialForm">
    <form action="#" method="POST">
        <div class="testimonialFormTitle">Write A Testimonials</div>
        <a class="closeTestimonialBtn"></a>
        <p><input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" id="tname" name="name" class="inputTxt placeholder"></p>
        <p><input type="text" placeholder="Your Email" id="temail" name="email" class="inputTxt placeholder"></p>
        <p><textarea placeholder="Testimonial" cols="50" rows="6" id="tmessage" name="message" class="inputTxtArea placeholder"></textarea></p>
        <a class="greyBtn" id="submitTestimonial" href="#">Submit</a>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't print_r the success. return it. Like this `return 'sucess';` And there's no die in javascript. Where's the view you make to submit your data?

Comment: i changed it ,but still same error show.

Comment: Where's the view to submit your forms?

Comment: Do you have DebugBar? See the route that Laravel is resolving https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Comment: Aldrin .I'm not able to post on controller page. Why Internal server error show.

Comment: @aniruddh please post your view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the csrf token.
When you do a post request there should always be a csrf token.

If you have created a form with illuminate/html facade then its quite simple

```
{!! Form::open() !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

If you do not have illuminate/html go to your composer.json file and add

```
"illuminate/html": "~5.0",
```

In the require block after laravel. After that run composer update and go to /config/app.php here you should add a new provider and alias

```
'providers' => [
    'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
],

'aliases' => [
    'Form' => 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade',
],
```

Now inside this form there is a hidden input field with the crsf token.
In you javascript file you can get this code with something like.

```
var data = {};
data._token = $('[name="_token"]').val();
```

Then send the data object with the ajax post call

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/testimonials/submit',
    method: 'POST',   
    data: data,            
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

And for test purpose you could change your function

```
public function savetesti()
{ 
    return 'success';
}
```